# Как получить отзывы страницы в Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Здравствуйте!

При попытки получении отзывов страницы в Facebook-е при помощи php SDK, просит permissions, как получить эти привилегии, или есть какие те другие идеи как можно получить Отзывы страницы.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Здравствуйте, Уважаемый Хакоб. Реализировать данный функционал можно, без костылей, только с помощью FacebookSDK. Я сейчас доберусь до ноутбука и опишу весь процесс

Comment: @RomanKozin Здравствуйте, спасибо за отклик, но уже нашли решение, еще раз спасибо большое! :)

Comment: тем не менее - я свой ответ оставлю)